# Search QuerySet of Dates Django

Tags: django

I have a **QuerySet of dates** in my Django project. Consider the following dates in the QuerySet as an example:

```
mm-dd-YYYY
01-15-2003
12-03-1971
04-23-1970
03-08-2005
```

Now, I also have a search bar to search through these dates. I want to enable the functionality so that the user can type "Jan" and all dates in January would remain. Or, if they were to type "J", then all dates in January, June, or July would remain.

**I guess, what I am asking, is how can I enable a search bar to filter through a QuerySet of dates?**

Comment: You need an AJAX call.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff Thanks for the response! I am more referring to the backend filtering side of things... what would the Django filter look like?

Comment: Convert string value to number of month with `calendar.month_abbr` or `datetime.strptime` and than filter by month. `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__month__in=[1,6,7])`.

Comment: @NKSM thanks for the response. But how would this work if someone types in "J", for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your search value to the number of month with `calendar.month_name` and then filter your QuerySet by month in list of your selected months.

```
value = "January 15"
search_date = value.strip(string.ascii_letters).strip()
search_month = value.strip(string.digits).strip()

months = [ k for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_name) if v.lower().startswith(search_month.lower()) ]

entries = Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__month__in=months)

if search_date:
    entries = entries.filter(pub_date__date=int(search_date))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will give it a shot and let you know

Comment: One question I had: if the search query is "January 15", then I don't want to show all january dates, only dates at january 15. How can I acheive this? Thank you for your help!